# PHP скрипт в cron задачу

Tags: php, cron

Уважаемые, долго голову ломал и гуглил, так и не нашел полностью рабочего примера. Вот эта задача cron, когда тестил, вроде сработала, когда завел окончательно в систему, то валится ошибка.

> `30  */12  *  *  *  /usr/bin/wget http://site.net/res/add.php?cs=2>>/home/www/site/log/loggraber.txt`

Вот ошибка:

> `CRON[17904]: (CRON) error (grandchild #17905 failed with exit status 2)`

Суть крона: в указанное время вызывался этот урл с параметром, ну, и лог выполнения я перекидываю в логи сайта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал как выше посоветовали, увы не помогло.

Убрал кидать в лог, cron сработал, но создаётся файл в рабочей директории add.php?cs=2 пустой. и при каждом выполнении крона новый создаётся там же.

Оставлю так.

Позже напишу ещё один крон, который будет удалять эти файлы.

Comment: Так не понятно.. а чего другого вы ожидали? Странно только что он пуст. Вы ведь не думали, что >> перенаправит результат загрузки из URL'а ?

Comment: Да фиг его, что я ожидал, скрипт после того, как отработает, отдаёт список изменений, вот и думал, что его сохранит, но увы PHP - это не Python. По этому не буду ломать голову, а допишу ещё один cron.  
Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: 30 */12 * * * /usr/bin/GET 'http://site.net/res/add.php?cs=2' >> /home/www/site/log/loggraber.txt

Answer (score 3):

Ну так ведь чёрным по белому сказано

> grandchild #17905 failed with exit status 2

Стало быть, не может wget выполниться и падает из-за ошибки 2

Смотрим [мануал](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html) и видим

> 2
>     Parse error—for instance, when parsing command-line options, the ‘.wgetrc’ or ‘.netrc’...

Стало быть, не удаётся параметры пропарсить. Я бы на вашем месте попробовал

```
30 */12 * * * /usr/bin/wget 'http://site.net/res/add.php?cs=2' >> /home/www/site/log/loggraber.txt
```

Comment: путь проверьте (/usr/bin/wget)
скорее всего вы переехали на freeBsd, а там путь будет такой:
/usr/local/bin/wget

или же команды wget нету вообще

Comment: **/usr/bin/wget** это точно, проверял когда нашёл этот способ, ОС Ubuntu